# Replacing list of li in a div with another list of li in the same div

Tags: jquery

How do I replace a list of li in a div with another list of li in the same div? I tried this:

```
   $("#divList").empty();
   $('#divList').append('<li>'  + textValue + '</li>');
```

I want to clear out all data that was originally in the div and replace data using the same div at the same margin-left and margin-top as first list of li.

In my code, the div is emptied, but the li is not appended.

Comment: What is textValue? Array, string, object?

Comment: What? ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏

Comment: I've read the question five times and I'm still not sure what you want to accomplish.

Comment: The question is really vague. Please go through the link on how to ask a question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: the problem I am having is how to clear out a div so that replace li data is seen

Comment: Help me help you fill in the blanks here:  You first want to Remove all child nodes from #divList, which you accomplished with .empty().  What is the significance of `at the same margin-left and margin-top as first list of li`?  Do you want it to just have the same formatting?  Why are you not accomplishing this via CSS (or is that part of the question)?  I'm better at straight JavaScript than JQuery but as far as the .append() section, I believe you have to create a node before you can attach it anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grab the new lists html and then replace it : http://jsfiddle.net/bikerabhinav/V6g8d/

```
//Assuming the new li items fall under ul#list-new
var list_new = $('#list_new').html();
//Now replace the old one
$('#list-old').empty().append(list_new);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#divList').html('').append('<li>'+textValue+'</li>');
```

Guestimate. Also, you do realise that this will just append 1 `li`, right?

Comment: There's no reason to set it to blank and then append... .html() will replace any content in the element. Just `$('#divList').html('<li>'+textValue+'</li>');` would do it.

Comment: @flexxy - Oh I know, but given the poster obviously doesn't have a clue what he's doing I figured this might make more sense to him.

Comment: Brogrammer is an upstanding citizen.

Comment: the append is there for a reason, the reason being I'm going through an each loop and appending li items in the div. During the second trigger of a this div loop, I want replace the original list data with list data on the second trigger